# Failed to start adb server in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, adb

Environment:

Windows 10 Pro

Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2

Android SDK Platform-tools 33.0.1 (adb)

Firstly I need to mention that the problem happened on one of my laptop. Only this laptop have this issue, which is strange. Also it's not because of the genymotion thing. Port 5037 is not occupied and I've tried all sorts of solutions such as killing adb process and restart, deleting the .android folder, reinstalling everything and so on...

**Problem**:

Every time I start android studio, it will automatically try to start the adb server. But **TWO adb processes** appear in the task manager,

[image]

and the event log in android studio keeps printing this:

***'...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary***

Then it will repeat over and over again.

I've also tried to start the adb server on different ports like 5038, it still doesn't work for most of the time.

However, I did succeed starting the adb server for twice, one after I deleted the .android folder and the other after I changed the adb port to 5038. I don't know why it suddenly worked and it won't be long before it starts to malfunction again, like after several hours.

I still cannot figure it out after a desperate struggle... I'm wondering if anyone has the same situation. If you need further clarification on something let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm having this problem on Windows 7.  The patch from your answer does not appear to have been installed on the machine in question.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Dale If you have tried those regular solutions like reinstalling AS, my suggest is to find another windows 7 on which adb works and compare the windows update patches between them. I know that looks stupid but it's really hard to locate the cause of the problem... It was just luck for me to find KB5013942 and I still don't know why it broke my adb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I found that windows update KB5013942 caused this problem. Uninstalling that patch will solve it. It only happened to certain PCs.